# Перезапись обычного символа в строке

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть переменная, содержимое которой мне неизвестно. В переменной содержатся символы, которые я хочу обновить, допустим, заменяемый символ второй переменной, тот, на который хочу заменить в третьей. Вот интересует, как это сделать?

```
// буквы "s" должны замениться на ничего, т.е. исчезнуть
$slovo = "nyadsfhh208fuh08un8eu0fh08euhf072h3s08fu0218uh3d078u2sh30d78";
$old_1 = "s";
$new_1 = "";    
// бурная деятельность
$slovo = "nyadfhh208fuh08un8eu0fh08euhf072h308fu0218uh3d078u2h30d78";

// буквы "s" должны замениться на "ы"
$slovo = "nyadsfhh208fuh08un8eu0fh08euhf072h3s08fu0218uh3d078u2sh30d78";
$old_1 = "s";
$new_1 = "ы";    
// бурная деятельность
$slovo = "nyadыfhh208fuh08un8eu0fh08euhf072h3ы08fu0218uh3d078u2ыh30d78";
```

p.s. единственное, что пришло в голову, это сделать explode, а потом implode ( научился час назад ) но, думаю, это не самое удачное решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$slovo = "nyadsfhh208fuh08un8eu0fh08euhf072h3s08fu0218uh3d078u2sh30d78";
$slovo2 = str_replace("s", "", $slovo);
```